Problems with react-native reanimated
Estou tendo problemas de build quando instalo essa biblioteca (I'm having build issues when installing this library)
I try npm run start --clear-cache and npx react-native run-android
my babel config has 'react-native-reanimated/plugin', and relativeSourceLocation: true,

Question is unclear, describe the exact issue you have encounterted



{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "prettier": "prettier --write ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.15",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.29",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.16.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-export-namespace-from": "^7.24.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.74.83",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.74.83",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.74.83",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.74.83",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  }
}



